# Making a 2D character array table in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, chararray

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
  char board[3][3];
  printf("Enter X or O>");
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        scanf("%c", &board[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("Board: ");
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        printf(" %c", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
/*Expected output: 
   X O X 
   O X O 
   X O O 
Actual output: 

  Board:  X
 O

 X

 O
 O
*/
```

I'm trying to make a 3x3 tic tac toe board using 2D arrays in C. This code works fine for an Int array but doesn't work as expected using char. I only get to input 5 characters for some reason instead of the 3x3=9 and the output is also jumbled. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @hade34 Use  scanf(" %c", &board[i][j]); See the blank before the symbol %

Comment: [You can fix by fixing input](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bbtuAXI8gt5YUYdS).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer

Comment: Short answer: With `%c` you read 5 expected chars and 4 newlines. Add a space before `%c` to skip whitespaces

Comment: Or just type all 9 input characters on one line.